# Recursive wget: alter links

Tags: ajax, linux, web, web-crawler, wget

I am trying to optimize my AJAX fragment links for Google crawler (which substitudes `"#!..."` links with `"?_escaped_fragment_=..."` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)). I want to check if the entire site is accessible via `_escaped_fragment_` links I have implemented.

I am curious if I can use `wget` recursive site download to this end and make it substitude `"#!"` links with `"_escaped_fragment_"`, so that wget sees

> abc.com?_escaped_fragment=arg=value

instead of

> abc.com#!arg=value

Answer (score 0):

No you can't strings after # is not sending to server... they are for JavaScript routing.